# Converting JSONL file to CSV - "JSONDecodeError: Extra data"

Tags: python, json, csv, tweepy

I am using tweepy's `Streamlistener` to collect Twitter Data and the code I am using generates a JSONL file with a bunch of meta data. 
Now I would like to convert the file into a CSV for which I found a code for just that. Unfortunately I have run into the Error reading:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 7833)
```

I have read through other threads and I reckon it has something to do with `json.loads` not being able to process multiple parts of data within the json file (which is of course the case for my json list file). 
How I can circumvent this problem within the code? Or do I have to use a completely different approach to convert the file? (I am using python 3.6, and the tweets I am streaming are mostly in Arabic).

```
__author__ = 'seandolinar'
import json
import csv
import io

'''
creates a .csv file using a Twitter .json file
the fields have to be set manually
'''

data_json = io.open('stream_____.jsonl', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read() #reads in the JSON file
data_python = json.loads(data_json)

csv_out = io.open('tweets_out_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') #opens csv file


fields = u'created_at,text,screen_name,followers,friends,rt,fav' #field names
csv_out.write(fields)
csv_out.write(u'\n')

for line in data_python:

#writes a row and gets the fields from the json object
#screen_name and followers/friends are found on the second level hence two get methods
row = [line.get('created_at'),
       '"' + line.get('text').replace('"','""') + '"', #creates double quotes
       line.get('user').get('screen_name'),
       unicode(line.get('user').get('followers_count')),
       unicode(line.get('user').get('friends_count')),
       unicode(line.get('retweet_count')),
       unicode(line.get('favorite_count'))]

row_joined = u','.join(row)
csv_out.write(row_joined)
csv_out.write(u'\n')




csv_out.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data file consists of multiple lines, each of which is a single json object, you can use a generator to decode the lines one at a time.

```
def extract_json(fileobj):
    # Using "with" ensures that fileobj is closed when we finish reading it.
    with fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            yield json.loads(line)
```

The only changes to your code is that the `data_json` file is not read explicitly, and `data_python` is the result of calling `extract_json` rather than `json.loads`.  Here's the amended code:

```
import json
import csv
import io

'''
creates a .csv file using a Twitter .json file
the fields have to be set manually
'''

def extract_json(fileobj):
    """
    Iterates over an open JSONL file and yields
    decoded lines.  Closes the file once it has been
    read completely.
    """
    with fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            yield json.loads(line)    


data_json = io.open('stream_____.jsonl', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') # Opens in the JSONL file
data_python = extract_json(data_json)

csv_out = io.open('tweets_out_utf8.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') #opens csv file


fields = u'created_at,text,screen_name,followers,friends,rt,fav' #field names
csv_out.write(fields)
csv_out.write(u'\n')

for line in data_python:

    #writes a row and gets the fields from the json object
    #screen_name and followers/friends are found on the second level hence two get methods
    row = [line.get('created_at'),
           '"' + line.get('text').replace('"','""') + '"', #creates double quotes
           line.get('user').get('screen_name'),
           unicode(line.get('user').get('followers_count')),
           unicode(line.get('user').get('friends_count')),
           unicode(line.get('retweet_count')),
           unicode(line.get('favorite_count'))]

    row_joined = u','.join(row)
    csv_out.write(row_joined)
    csv_out.write(u'\n')

csv_out.close()
```

Comment: I understand your answer content wise, but technically how do I set up the data? Do I have to change the letters or numbers depending on my data? Also do I then just include the first two blogs of your suggested code as the first lines in my code? Hope these aren't very naive questions (newbie). Thanks again! (Btw. when running it, I ran into a syntax error message for <process data> )

Comment: @JosephinaK. I've  amended the answer to remove the confusing usage example and add a complete version of your code.

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot. I had to make some small changes to the original code (change unicode to str and add utf-8-sig for excel) but now it runs well :) One last thing: when opening the file, the reader seems to confuse texts that include "=" and separates them into a separate column which then messes up the whole order. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @JosephinaK.  It'll probably end up being a new question, but opening which file?  The jsonl or the csv that you create?

Comment: It's in the created csv file!

Comment: Try creating the csv using the functions in the [csv package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).  In particular, use a `csv.writer` and use the `writerow(s)` methods.  If you have difficulty getting it to work jsut ask a new question.  The issue is most like that `=` needs to be properly escaped to prevent excel interpreting it as the start of a formula; `csv.writer` and friends should ensure that the correct escaping is applied.

Comment: okay! I will try with that and see how far I can get.. Thanks again.